# Why is my browser to wait?

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, long-polling

The first, thank you for see this my post, I use AJAX to send request to server PHP (laravel) and the server will handle request (about 10sec) before return it for AJAX. But, when AJAX request waiting, I open other browser to access my webpage -> It still wait for 10s. I don't understand???
**My js**

```js
function pullRequest() {
  /* send request to server */
  var xhr = $.ajax({
    method: 'POST',
    url: 'pull?random_key='+Math.floor(Math.random()*10),
    data: {'_token':$('meta[name=csrf-token]').attr('content')},
    success: function(response) {
      /* pull request */
      pullRequest();
    },
  }); /* end ajax */
  $('a[href]').click(function() {
    xhr.abort();
  });
} /* end function pullRequest */

$(function() {
  // pullRequest();
  setTimeout('pullRequest()', 2000);
});
```

**My php**

```
public function handle(Request $request) {
  $time = time()+50;
  while(1) {
    echo connection_status();
    if($this->hasNewMessages() || time() >= $time) {
      break;
    }
    continue;
  }
  return $this->messages;
}
```

I have record a video about it. I am sorry, cause I don't know insert it. Please, follow link youtube: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8jqPU3R-60I

**Thank you for reading**

Comment: There are two common reasons for this:  the web server's configuration and PHP sessions.  If you can, you should always close your sessions as soon as possible with `session_write_close()`: http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-write-close.php

Comment: I tried add `session_write_close()`  into while loop, It's not working...

Comment: It wouldn't belong in the loop but apparently that's not your problem.  What is your web server and do you have access to its configuration?

Comment: I using localhost (laravel framework), I access all permission to it.

Comment: That wasn't the question but now you bring up another one:  Is your client browser on the same machine as the server?  Please do answer my previous question on what web server you're using (Apache/Nginx/IIS).

Comment: I start laravel using command `php artisan serve`. I just try create a project from apache2. Then, sleep It for 10sec. I open two web browser. 
strangely, Just my Laravel session waiting, Apache2 still normal. I think reason from laravel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the command `php artisan serve`, you are actually starting PHP's builtin web server.

As noted in the PHP manual:

> Warning
>
> This web server was designed to aid application development. It may also be useful for testing purposes or for application demonstrations that are run in controlled environments. It is not intended to be a full-featured web server. It should not be used on a public network.

If you want a production grade installation or any additional features, you need to use a separate web server such as Apache (which you mistakenly though you were using).

Comment: Omg! I mistakenly about it. Thank you very much.